# Missing case of value on input type="hidden"

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I faced with missing case sensitive string value, how it can be fixed?

Example is following: 
..

```
 entity.Value = "Some Test Value";
 entity.Name = "SomeTestName";
```

..

When I place it in View like following (I am using Razor),

```
<input type="hidden" name="@entity.Name" value="@entity.Value">
```

Then it will be rendered as following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SomeTestName" value="some test value">
```

I used

```
<input type="hidden" name="@entity.Name" value="@Html.Raw(entity.Value)">
```

but result is the same.

So, its missing case. How it can be fixed?

Comment: Can you confirm that if you just emit the value *outside* the input tag, that it renders with the proper case?

Comment: Yes. That's renders fine outside.

Comment: What's the output with  value='@Html.Raw(entity.Value)' ?

Comment: Methinks the offending code is missing, add more code from your controller. From what you posted, you should be getting the correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be the case (status no-repro).

Model:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var entity = new Entity();
        entity.Value = "Some Test Value";
        entity.Name = "SomeTestName";
        return View(entity);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Entity
<input type="hidden" name="@Model.Name" value="@Model.Value" />
```

Generated HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SomeTestName" value="Some Test Value" />
```

See? Everything works perfectly fine. So we can draw only a single conclusion here: you haven't shown your full code allowing us to reproduce your problem rendering your question meaningless.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, there is another code that makes string.toLower.